# Pytorch: randomly subsample a vector

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, pytorch

I need to randomly subsample a vector in pytorch. 
The equivalent in Matlab would be something like

```
sample_size = 5
a = rand(10,1)
idx = randperm(10)
b = a(idx(1:sample_size))
```

Are there similar functions for pytorch?

I'm trying to randomly subsample my prediction and target vector for computing the loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I already found something useful:

```
sample_size = 5
a = torch.randn(10)
b = torch.randperm(10)
a = a.index_select(0,b)
a = a[0:sample_size]
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could simply do:

```
sample_size = 5
a = torch.randn(10)
b = torch.randperm(10)
a_sample = a[b[0:sample_size]]
```

that is to sample without replacement like in your question.

Or if you want to sample with replacement:

```
sample_size = 5
a = torch.randn(10)
b = torch.randint(0, 10, size=(sample_size,))
a_sample = a[b]
```